# mySql - how to select with conditional count, X items on one table relating to a record in the other

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: articles, and article_comments (article_comments has an article_id fk...)
I need to select the articles details that has only 1 comment only related to them
(or any other fixed number, 1 is just as an example)

I tried something like this and got an error:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles a, article_comments ac
WHERE a.article_id = ac.article_id
AND COUNT(ac.article_id) = 1
GROUP BY ac.article_id;
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @navi it was tag with `MySQL` `:)`

Comment: My bad. Dint check that :P

Answer (score 1):

Your answers is `HAVING count(ac.article) = 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    articles a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  article_id, COUNT(*) totalComments
            FROM    article_comments 
            GROUP   BY article_id
            HAVING  COUNT(*) = 1  -- change the value here
        ) b     ON a.article_id = b.article_id
```

Comment: @navi can you site why? where did the query violated?

Comment: The `select from ( select)` structure was what I was worried about. Most of the common database platforms support this query, however, the informix and sybase (not 100% sure) do not support this structure. The inner join above uses a select result set as a table, which might not be supported.

Comment: @navi ah ok `:D` but i'm sure this will be supported on Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL. `:)`

Comment: I guess for the purpose of this question, your answer is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
 a.article_id,
 count(c.article_id)
FROM
 articles a
JOIN
 article_comments c ON c.article_id = a.article_id
GROUP BY 1
HAVING count(c.article_id) = 1;
```

Comment: this will not get all columns from `articles` table.